# Any difference between $injector and Inject() in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, mocking

Is there any difference/preference between:

```
inject(function($injector) {
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
});
```

And

```
inject(function($rootScope){
    rootScope = $rootScope;
});
```

Are the eqal as far as getting a resource injected into a test in Jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on the inject function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject):

> The inject function wraps a function into an injectable function. The
>   inject() creates new instance of $injector per test, which is then
>   used for resolving references.

So, to answer your question, no, there really isn't a difference in the two ways, other than (in my opinion) it's a lot easier to just use the inject function to get dependencies instead of going through the `$injector`